# How does a MRI use 20.1kW yet creates over 204K BTU/h?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation, energy-conservation

I've been reading through a manual about MRI operating procedures for a large healthcare provider. The manual (written by Siemens) states that the MRI machines use 9kW in stand-by mode and 20.1kW while operating - yet the cooling system is required to move 204K+ BTU/h.

I'm confused as to where all the extra heat is coming from as 20.1kW[image] should be 71k+ BTU/h.

Where is the extra ~140k BTU/h coming from?

Comment: Welcome to the physics.SE ! This is a question and answer community addressing physics. For this kind of questions, you should consider asking directly the company (Siemens) or at least a dedicated forum of users.

Answer (score 2):

The MRI machine has to be kept below room temperature. This means that while some of the 204K BTU/h that needs to be dissipated comes from the machine, the majority comes from the hospital's heating system. Heat from the environment warms the machine and that needs to be dissipated too.

Comment: This. Maintaining supper-conducting equipment is expensive in terms of air conditioning, ad it gets worse if you are trying to maintain isolated small machines. Particle physics labs with lots of superconducting bits to support install centralized nitrogen and helium liquifiers and pump the stuff around the site.

Comment: Mmmmmmmm..... supper-conducting equipment

Comment: @Jim: That was probably a Freudian slip from his stomach. I often wished something like that if the measurement keeps going and going...

Comment: This is wrong. "**Typical** power consumption during exam" = 20 kW. However, during a gradient intensive pulse sequence and with the RF power going full bore, the power is significantly higher. That is why there's a factor 3x - you need to be able to take away the peak heat, not just the mean heat. Heat load into the cryo system is a small fraction of the total power used (it is well insulated). I am looking at a datasheet right now (GE 750w) that shows 20 kVA peak use for cryo and heat exchanger, and 103 kVA peak for the MR system (gradient and RF). The peak load is the problem.

Comment: @Floris Wow, that's a late critique on a post. You have my permission to make whatever changes you think are necessary to correct the answer, if you want. Alternatively, you can post a different correct answer and I'll support it. But at this point, it's too long ago and too insignificant of a post for me to try to get back into it now.

Comment: @ACuriousJim - late, yes. The marvels of the internet. Your digital footprint lasts "forever". Thanks for the invitation to edit - I cannot add my own answer as the question is closed.

Comment: @Floris I made it community wiki so that you can edit all you want and I don't get any rep for it. (I got it wrong. That doesn't deserve rep)